# Xcode swift 3 sprite kit animate a image that go up and down

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

hello I'm coding a app on xcode and i really like to know how to move a SKSpriteNode up and down smooth kind of animated 
(just like the in Pop The Lock when you complete the level)

SKSpriteNode code

```
    Lock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Lock")
    Lock.size = CGSize(width: 182, height: 170)
    Lock.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: (self.frame.height / 2 + 180))
    Lock.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(Lock)
```

Comment: One possible way is to use [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/) class. Another way is to change position property inside of an update: method. Also it is possible to move sprites using physics engine.

Comment: I gonna try this thanks for reply

Comment: how do i do that i try this                                                                            self.Lock.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, -10)) self.Lock.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 60)) and it gave me this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Answer (score 0):

You can use SKAction for example.

```
//Move Up
let MoveUp = SKAction.MoveToY(self.frame.height / 2 + 280) // +100 up
Lock.runAction(MoveUp)

//Move Down
let MoveDown = SKAction.MoveToY(self.frame.height / 2 + 80) // -100 down
Lock.runAction(MoveDown)
```